# Add files button not working if more than one (jquery File Upload Plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I am using jquery file-upload plugin in backbone js. 
I have more than one add-files button on a same page. **Each button comes form their respective backbone views**.

```
**View**
render: ->
  $(@el).html(@template(model: @model.attributes ))
  @

**Template**
<form id="fileupload" class="fileupload" action="some_action" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <span class="btn btn-xs btn-success fileinput-button">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
    <span>Add files...</span>
    <input type="file" class="select_file" name="files" multiple>
  </span>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary start">
     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
     <span>Start upload</span>
  </button>

</form>
```

**The Add files button works for any one form but not for the others**

What can be the reason and how to solve it?

Comment: The posted code works perfectly fine, and just as intended, as it's just a snippet of HTML without any javascript or context ?

Comment: Above code works for the first form but not for the others. I am able to select files from any one 'Add Files' button and I am also able to upload the files. But  from other 'Add Files' button I am not even able to select files.

Comment: And do all these forms have their own unique ID, that the fileupload plugin has been initialized on?

Comment: You mean the Add files... *span*? Why would a `<span>` act like a button? What do your events look like? What is the view's `el`? There's not enough information here to reproduce or diagnose your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [jsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/eLLWN/249/).

My guess is, you might have initialized fileupload like below in your code.

```
$("#fileupload").fileupload(....)
```

If you have done like that it should be the issue. You should initialize fileupload on each form.

**Note:**
I found this jsFiddle on google search and edited it for your requirement.